# Heroku Shared PostgreSQL and pgcrypto

Tags: postgresql, heroku

I'm wondering if there is any way to enable pgcrypto on the Heroku Shared PostgreSQL database (5mb)?  I have it working fine on my local dev box, but it complains about not being able to find gen_salt when I push to Heroku.

If not, should I use a library to deal with passwords/salts at the business logic layer and store the salt & passhash in the database as straight character fields?

Thanks so much!

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure what I can say, but pgcrypto is coming.

There's evidence of this from pvh on Hacker News: http://news.ycombinator.com/item?id=2942210

Comment: I just read through the post on HN, that's great to hear!  I've got a 'plan b' solution in place for now, but I'm going to have to beef it up before my site goes live.